# How to copy and replace an application via Terminal in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

What could the correct Terminal `cp` syntax may be? I tried use syntax cp -R ~/Downloads/MyApp.app /Application and in Terminal many questions apeared e.g.: `overwrite /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Resouces/app/apm/index.js (y/n [n])`. 
How can I copy and replace an application via Terminal in Mac OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `/bin/cp -rf ~/Downloads/MyApp.app /Application`

`-f` force and prevent any question

Comment: I've just tried, but added the key `-f` isn't working.

Comment: did you call `/bin/cp` ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. After I used `/bin/cp` all is OK. You are a Wizard! Thanks!

Comment: i've tried but it only replace version not App icon Any Suggestion ?